# Pull text from website

Tags: web-scraping

I have a task in front of me to document many many thousands of public land information
and i record it on a spreadsheet basically. There's 3 pieces of information i need from these records. SECTION TOWNSHIP RANGE that's all I care about.

http://i843.photobucket.com/albums/zz360/mattr1992/ndrin_zpsdc360ac8.png

Here's my resources as you can see each entry has what I'm looking for section/township/range although they are all unique entries and not the same

I would like to pull the section/township/range of each entry into a spreadsheet. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy the webpage into a plain text file, you could use the regular expression like `section: [0-9]* township: [0-9]* range: [0-9]*` to capture all the information, and then import to Excel, which could easily separate them into different sheet.